# CiviCRM Event Registrations Malformed

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

We're still on an ancient version of CiviCRM (4.7.x) and CiviDiscount (3.2) and Drupal 7.x

A small number of our event registrations are coming in with no price set options actually selected. It's dumping all of the options into the "Event Level" field. Pictured below.

When I select "Change Selections" all of the price set options are blank/not selected. We received payment for the correct choices, however. Does anyone know what's causing this for sure? I want to upgrade our site, but not recklessly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe this is a reporting issue and not a data issue - but you should upgrade a *test* copy of your site to be sure.

Comment: How would you recommend I check the DB to find out? I added a screenshot for two database values. Anything else I could probe into?

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech I have updated to recent CiviCRM 5.5.1 and there is no change.

Comment: Did you replicate this on civicrm master demo site?

Comment: I will attempt to do that next. It seems like the error occurs when someone uses a discount code on a price set item and chooses pay later option. Some, but not all cases. Very strange.

Comment: would be helpful if you can provide steps to replicate.

Comment: Pradeep, part of the issue is I can't seem to replicate it. We have hundreds of registrations and some just come in like this. That's why I posted the data in the DB tables - is there anything corrupted, or anywhere else I could look? Good records look identical to bad ones.